# C# MongoClient Profiling Query Duration

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I like to profile my MongoDB commands and if duration exceeds a limit I like to write a warning into log.
Profiling/monitoring with the Java implemntation is well documented (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/monitoring/)) but for the .net driver I didn't found any doucmentation on https://www.mongodb.com/docs/.

I stumbled over this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284212/profiling-mongodb-queries-when-using-c-sharp-driver), but there the profiling is set on the MongoDB level. I want it to be configurable in my C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "hidden" documentation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/c8a34e1c0ef355dde28c2556e56d87b32782600a/Docs/reference/content/reference/driver_core/events.md).

And the solution I applied is:

```
 public MongoClient Create(string connectionString)
{
    var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
    settings.ClusterConfigurator = clusterBuilder =>
    {
        clusterBuilder.Subscribe<CommandSucceededEvent>(x => CheckDuration(x.Duration,x.CommandName));
        clusterBuilder.Subscribe<CommandFailedEvent>(x => CheckDuration(x.Duration, x.CommandName));
    };
    return new MongoClient(settings);
}

private void CheckDuration(TimeSpan duration, string commandName)
{
    if (duration.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
        Log.Warn($"Command {commandName} took longer than 100 ms Duration={duration.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
}
```